# What is the fastest way to get a high multiplier and score?

Tags: all-zombies-must-die-scorepocalypse

With the new [Scorepocalypse](http://store.steampowered.com/app/209360/) spin-off from All Zombies Must Die, I have the problem that I am sometimes already at wave 50, but score is still around 100.000 only.
Silver Medal is 400.000 Score.

From what I understand, Zombies with status effects ( sonic, fire, mutated etc. ) give the multiplier as long as they live and it drops when zombies with a special status die.

But in the same time, those special zombies are very fast and become a threat pretty quick.

So what is the best strategy to acummulate a high score and multiplier early on and are there any other factors that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no answer yet, I paste the one from the developer of the game on steam forums:

> There are a few good ways to improve your multiplier, and therefore
>   your scores, here are some tips:
>
> 1. Collect Z'Orbs, don't get hit by zombies. Z'Orbs contribute to
>      your temporary multiplier (albeit a small amount), however they are
>      knocked back down by a certain percentage every time you get hit.
>      This requires quite some skill, but if you master being hit as
>      little as possible your scores will improve.
> 2. Make use of the status effects. I don't just mean keeping zombies
>      on fire or sonified, there are other side effects too. Try spawning
>      a few mutants with radiation and see what happens to your
>      multiplier..
> 3. This is an obvious one but challenges, challenges, challenges...
>      the more you complete earlier on in the level, the higher your
>      multiplier stays permanently. The quicker you complete them the
>      faster a new challenge will appear too!
> 4. Get rid of those pesky necromancer zombies when they appear...
>      ghosts give no score when killed!
>
> Hope this helps, happy zombie slaying!
>
> Kind regards, Stanith

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=30436831&postcount=4